# Difficulties with math formatting in LNCS

Tags: math-mode, lncs

I have some more problems I can't figure out how to solve and I need to finish this for tomorrow, so it would be nice if you could check out what's wrong (and especially how to fix it). Thanks a lot! I've pasted it here http://pastebin.com/JbVCu8nQ so it doesn't clutter this site.

Comment: From taking a quick peak at your code, I'd say that almost all of the `array` environments really ought to be typeset as `tabular` environments. Also, there's absolutely no need to encase paragraphs in `\paragraph{...}` statements.

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are "too localized" since it won't help future visitors to the site very much. Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: as Mico said, the pararaphs should _not_ be in `\paragraph`. In LaTeX `\paragraph` is a sectioning command one level below `\subsubsection` so you have made (subsubsub)sections with very long titles and no text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Line 47: You're using math without specifying the mode as such:

  ```
  ... $D = (A \wedge B) \vee (B \wedge C)$ ...
  ```
- Line 59: You're using a URL with `_` which is considered a math subscript. You should replace this with `\textunderscore` or use a suitable URL-typesetting package, like [`url`](http://ctan.org/pkg/url):

  ```
  \usepackage{url}% http://ctan.org/pkg/url
  %...
  \begin{thebibliography}{999}
   \bibitem{00} \url{http://homepages.fh-friedberg.de/euler/wi/skript.pdf} (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
   \bibitem{01} \url{http://www.semibyte.de/wp/download/maths/aussagenlogik.pdf} (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
   \bibitem{02} \url{http://mo.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/kurse/kurs7/seite1.html} (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
   \bibitem{03} \url{http://haegar.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/personen/ehemalig/vollmer/Vorlesungen/logik_f_inf_skript_2.pdf} (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
  \end{thebibliography}
  ```

Apart from that, the document compiles.

---

For completeness, here is the original file:

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\title{Aussagenlogik}
\author{some guy}
\institute{some place}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Einleitung}
\paragraph{Eine Aussage ist ein Satz, der einen eindeutigen Wahrheitsgehalt hat, d.h. eine Aussage kann entweder wahr oder falsch sein, aber nicht beides zur gleichen Zeit. Verschiedene Aussagen k\"{o}nnen \"{u}ber diverse Operationen (z.B. Konjunktionen oder Disjunktionen), miteinander zu einer neuen Aussage verkn\"{u}pft werden, die wiederum einen eigenen Wahrheitswert besitzt.}

\section{Definition einer Aussage und dessen Wahrheitswert}
\paragraph{Eine Aussage ist ein Satz, der allgemein g\"{u}ltig entweder wahr oder falsch ist, aber zur gleichen Zeit nicht beides sein kann. \"{U}ber S\"{a}tze in der Form "`Die europ\"{a}ische Union hat 2012 den Friedensnobelpreis erhalten"' oder "`Barack Obama ist der zweiundvierzigste Pr\"{a}sident der Vereinigten Staaten von Amerika"' l\"{a}sst sich sagen, ob sie wahr oder falsch sind; in diesem Falle ist der erste Satz wahr und der zweite Satz falsch. Der Satz "`Am Sonntag ist sch\"{o}nes Wetter"' kann nicht allgemein als wahr oder falsch bezeichnet werden, da die Definition von „sch\"{o}n“ je nach Person variiert, z.B. empfinden manche Personen Sonnenschein und andere Personen Regen als sch\"{o}nes Wetter. Der Wahrheitswert einer Aussage muss dabei nicht bekannt sein, die Aussage "`Jede gerade Zahl $\ge 4$ l\"{a}sst sich als Summe zweier Primzahlen schreiben"' ist zwar bisher weder bewiesen noch widerlegt worden, es ist aber prinzipiell m\"{o}glich zu sagen, ob dieser Satz allgemein g\"{u}ltig ist oder nicht.\cite{02}\\ \\}

A sei eine Aussage. Dann ist der Wahrheitswert W(A) wie folgt definiert:
\[W(A) = \begin{cases} \mathit{wahr}, \text{wenn A zutrifft}\\ \mathit{falsch}, \text{wenn A nicht zutrifft}
\end{cases}\]
\cite{00}

\section{Verkn\"{u}pfungen mehrerer Aussagen}
\paragraph{Aus zwei Aussagen A und B l\"{a}sst sich mithilfe verschiedener Verkn\"{u}pfungen eine neue Aussage C erstellen, dessen Wahrheitsgehalt von dem Wahrheitsgehalt der Aussagen A und B abh\"{a}ngig ist. Zu den drei Grundverkn\"{u}pfungen z\"{a}hlen dabei die Negation, die Konjunktion sowie die Disjunktion.\cite{00}}

\subsection{Negation}
\paragraph{Bei der Negation (beschrieben durch den Operator $\neg$)wird der Wahrheitsgehalt einer Aussage A umgekehrt. Dies entspricht einer Umkehrung der Definition des Wahrheitsgehalts W(X) einer normalen Aussage.\cite{03}}

Sei A eine Aussage. Dann ist $\neg(A)$ wie folgt definiert:
\[\neg(A) = \begin{cases} \mathit{falsch}, \text{wenn A zutrifft}\\ \mathit{wahr}, \text{wenn A nicht zutrifft}
\end{cases}\]

\subsection{Konjunktion}
\paragraph{Bei der Konjunktion (beschrieben durch den Operator $\wedge$) wird aus zwei Aussagen A und B eine neue Aussage C gebildet, die genau dann wahr ist, wenn sowohl A als auch B wahr sind, andernfalls ist die Aussage C falsch. Die Wahrheitstabelle dieser Operation sieht entsprechend wie folgt aus:\cite{03}}

$\begin{array}{c|c||c|}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{B}&\mathbf{A\wedge B}\\\hline wahr&wahr&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline wahr&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\\\hline falsch&wahr&\mathbf{falsch}\\\hline falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\end{array}$
\cite{01}

\subsection{Disjunktion}
\paragraph{Bei der Disjunktion (beschrieben durch den Operator $\vee$) wird aus zwei Aussagen A und B eine neue Aussage C gebildet, die genau dann wahr ist, wenn eine der beiden Aussagen A oder B wahr ist, andernfalls ist die Aussage C falsch. Die Wahrheitstabelle dieser Operation sieht entsprechend wie folgt aus:\cite{03}}

$\begin{array}{c|c||c|}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{B}&\mathbf{A \vee B}\\\hline wahr&wahr&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline wahr&falsch&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline falsch&wahr&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\end{array}$
\cite{01}

\section{Ausdr\"{u}cke}
\paragraph{Neben einfachen Verkn\"{u}pfungen lassen sich beliebig viele Aussagen mit den Grundverkn\"{u}pfungen zu einer neuen Aussage verbinden lassen, dessen Wahrheitsgehalt von den einzelnen Wahrheitsgehalten der Aussagen und den angewandten Verkn\"{u}pfungen abh\"{a}ngt. So k\"{o}nnte man beispielsweise die Aussage D = (A \wedge B) \vee (B \wedge C) definieren, die genau dann wahr ist, wenn sowohl A und B oder B und C wahr ist, wie sich aus der folgenden Wahrheitstabelle ablesen l\"{a}sst:\cite{00}}

$\begin{array}{c|c|c||c|c|c|}\mathbf{A}&\mathbf{B}&\mathbf{C}&\mathbf{A \wedge  B}&\mathbf{B \wedge  C}&\mathbf{(A \wedge  B) \vee  (B \wedge  C)}\\\hline wahr&wahr&wahr&wahr&wahr&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline wahr&wahr&falsch&wahr&falsch&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline wahr&falsch&wahr&falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\\\hline wahr&falsch&falsch&falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\\\hline falsch&wahr&wahr&falsch&wahr&\mathbf{wahr}\\\hline falsch&wahr&falsch&falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\\\hline falsch&falsch&wahr&falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\\\hline falsch&falsch&falsch&falsch&falsch&\mathbf{falsch}\end{array}$
\cite{00}

\section{Fazit}
\paragraph{Nicht jeder Satz ist auch gleichzeitig eine Aussage, sondern ausschließlich solche, die wahr oder falsch sein k\"{o}nnen. Mit den grundlegenden Verkn\"{u}pfungsoperatoren der Negation, der Konjunktion und der Disjunktion k\"{o}nnen verschiedene Aussagen zu neuen Aussagen geformt werden, die wiederum abh\"{a}ngig von den Wahrheitsgehalten der Aussagen und der benutzten Operationen einen eigenen Wahrheitsgehalt haben. Hierbei k\"{o}nnen die Operationen mit beliebig vielen Aussagen und Verkn\"{u}pfungen kombiniert werden.}

\begin{thebibliography}{999}
  \bibitem{00} http://homepages.fh-friedberg.de/euler/wi/skript.pdf (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
  \bibitem{01} http://www.semibyte.de/wp/download/maths/aussagenlogik.pdf (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
  \bibitem{02} http://mo.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/kurse/kurs7/seite1.html (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
  \bibitem{03} http://haegar.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/personen/ehemalig/vollmer/Vorlesungen/logik_f_inf_skript_2.pdf (abgerufen am 16.10.2012)
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```